# Isomorphic Group Extensions

Tags: group-theory, group-extensions

I need to make a statement which I think should be an elementary group theory fact.  Here is the setup.  I have two exact sequences of groups:
$$ 1\longrightarrow \ker\varphi_1\longrightarrow G\overset{\varphi_1}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{R}$$
$$ 1\longrightarrow \ker\varphi_2\longrightarrow G\overset{\varphi_2}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{R}$$

The groups $G$ are the same (they are discrete countable groups, but not necessarily finitely generated).  I can prove the kernels of the homomorphisms are equal.  Moreover, the images are both discrete subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.  I would like to conclude that there is a homomorphism $\psi\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$  (necessarily multiplication by some number) such that $\varphi_2=\psi\circ\varphi_1$.

Since the image of $\varphi_i$ is discrete in $\mathbb{R}$, we can just pretend the $\mathbb{R}$'s are $\mathbb{Z}$'s and rephrase the question as follows: I have two short exact sequences of groups, and I have maps in the first and second columns making the diagram commute.  I want to conclude there is a map in the third column making the entire diagram commute.

Comment: You already say that the images are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ so infinite cyclic. Say one image is generated by $x$ and the other by $y$. Then it seems like multiplying with $y/x$ gives the result.

Comment: @Levent That is definitely the correct homomorphism between the copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, but how do you show that it makes the diagram commute?  You start with $g\in G$ which is not in the kernel.  Then define $\psi$ via multiplication by $\varphi_2(g)/\varphi_1(g)$.  Now you have to show that if $h\in G$, then $\psi\circ\varphi_1(h)=\varphi_2(h)$.

Comment: The elementary fact that $\frac{\varphi_2(g)}{\varphi_1(g)}\cdot \varphi_1(g)=\varphi_2(g)$ gives what you want (what I mean is if you define $\psi(x)=\frac{\varphi_2(g)}{\varphi_1(g)}\cdot x$ then $\psi(\varphi_1(g))=\varphi_2(g)$)

Comment: @Levent.  It's not that simple.  That tells you the diagram commutes on $\langle g\rangle\leq G$.  But you *defined* the homomorphism using $g$.  Then you need to show that the diagram commutes for all $h\in G$.  So you want to show that $\varphi_2(g)/\varphi_1(g)\cdot \varphi_1(h)=\varphi_2(h)$.

Comment: Well, since $G/Ker\varphi_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, you already know that $gKer\varphi_1$ generates the quotient, so if $h\in G$ then $h=g^n\cdot u$ for some $u\in Ker\varphi_1$, hence $\frac{\varphi_2(g)}{\varphi_1(g)}\cdot \varphi_1(h)=\varphi_2(g)\cdot n=\varphi_2(h)$ (since $\varphi_1(h)=n\cdot g$) which is what you want.

Comment: Btw, it seems like without loss of generality you can assume that kernels are trivial, so $G$ is already infinite cyclic.